# How can I create pojo class of json array

Tags: java, android, json, api, retrofit

How can I create pojo class of this type of JsonArray
Below links response
https://fakestoreapi.com/products/categories

```
[
"electronics",
"jewelery",
"men's clothing",
"women's clothing"
]
```

Comment: This is just an Array of String i.e `ArrayList<String>` should work  why you need a class for it ?

Comment: List or array of strings will do the job for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Use ArrayList Of String

```
public class ClassName{
  @JsonProperty("MyArray") 
  public ArrayList<String> myArray;
}
```